# Resize table to dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have a dictionary populated from another table and I want to post the keys in the dictionary into my main table. The main table doesn't resize to match the count of keys.

```
Sub A_Unique_B()
Dim X
Dim objDict As Object
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim tbl_o As ListObject

Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").ListObjects("tbl_data")
Set tbl_o = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").ListObjects("tbl_overview")
Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

X = Application.Transpose(tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange)

For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
    objDict(X(lngRow)) = 1
Next

With tbl_o
    ' Some code here maybe?
    .ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange = Application.Transpose(objDict.Keys)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.Resize(objDict.count)` ?

Comment: @PeterT returns `invalid use of property`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the code so it works:

```
Sub A_Unique_B()
Dim X
Dim objDict As Object
Dim lngRow As Long
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim tbl_o As ListObject
Dim keycount As Long
Dim lr As Long

Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").ListObjects("tbl_data")
Set tbl_o = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview").ListObjects("tbl_overview")
Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

X = Application.Transpose(tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange)

For lngRow = LBound(X, 1) To UBound(X, 1)
    objDict(X(lngRow)) = 1
Next
keycount = objDict.Count


With tbl_o
   .Resize Range("C6:J" & keycount + 6)
    .ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange = Application.Transpose(objDict.Keys)
End With

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Overview")
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("C" & keycount + 7 & ":J" & lr).ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm glad you achieved a workable solution. One suggestion is to use both `LBound` and `UBound` for looping over a dynamically created array. The lower bounds can be 0 or 1, depending on how the array is created. So `For lngRow = LBound(X, 1) to UBound(X, 1)` will always work for you.

Comment: You are correct that it is more robust. Edited my answer.